# On section 15.44 (The singular locus) of the Stacks Project

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

My question is about Lemma 15.44.2 from the Stacks Project:

**Lemma 15.44.2** Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring. Let $X = \text{Spec}(R)$.
The ring $R$ is J-1 (i.e. $\text{Reg}(X)$ is open) if and only if $V(\mathfrak p) \cap \text{Reg}(X)$
contains a nonempty open subset of $V(\mathfrak p)$ for all
$\mathfrak p \in \text{Reg}(X)$.

The proof refers to the following lemma from topology:

**Lemma 5.16.5** Let $X$ be a Noetherian topological space.
Let $E \subset X$ be a subset.
The following are equivalent:

(1) $E$ is open in $X$, and

(2) for every irreducible closed subset $Y$ of $X$
the intersection $E \cap Y$ is either empty or
contains a nonempty open of $Y$.

I am aware that $X = \text{Spec}(R)$ is a Noetherian topological space as $R$ is a Noetherian ring and that the sets $V(\mathfrak p)$, $\mathfrak p \in \text{Spec}(R)$, are precisely the irreducible closed subsets of $X$. Further, $V(\mathfrak p) \cap \text{Reg}(X) \neq \emptyset$ if $\mathfrak p \in \text{Reg}(X)$, as clearly $\mathfrak p \in V(\mathfrak p)$.

**My question:** Why does it suffice in Lemma 15.44.2 to consider only prime ideals $\mathfrak p \in \text{Reg}(X)$ (and not $\mathfrak p \in \text{Spec}(X)$)? Or in other words, what happens to $V(\mathfrak p) \cap \text{Reg}(X)$ if $\mathfrak p \not\in \text{Reg}(X)$?

I am grateful for any help.

Comment: Please give a reference where we can understand what is "Stacks Project". Any ressemblance with "Stackexchange" :)) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Not sure if you're joking, but here's the link to the material in question: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07P6

Comment: @Quasicoherent It was a half joke. I thank you very much : I had really no idea that such a compendium exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key fact you need to use is that a localization of a regular local ring is regular, so $\operatorname{Reg}(X)$ is stable under generalization.  This means that if $\operatorname{Reg}(X)\cap V(\mathfrak{p})$ is nonempty, then $\mathfrak{p}\in\operatorname{Reg}(X)$.  So if $\mathfrak{p}\not\in \operatorname{Reg}(X)$, then $\operatorname{Reg}(X)\cap V(\mathfrak{p})$ is empty and condition (2) of Lemma 5.16.5 is still satisfied.